# An Easier Way to Control Test Order in TestNG?

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I've seen a few similar questions posted but none that quite answered my question directly...
I'm using Selenium Webdriver 2.0 with TestNg and Java and I'm looking for a better way to control the order in which tests are run.
Really all I want is the tests cases to run in the order they're written in the classes.
It's intuitive. Its easy. Its maintainable. And I'm really surprised it's not the default for testNg.
(Why apply some random ordering when it's not explicitly requested by the coder?)

Anyway, I know that I can add a list of methods to my testng xml, but I have 130 tests so far (and several hundred to come!) and such a method list will be far too much for future maintenance.
EG when I add ten test methods I'll have to remember to add all those methods to my xml file. And what happens if I miss adding one? I'll never notice that it was never run...

So this solution would be a maintenance nightmare:

```
<test name="BVTQA01">
 <classes>
  <class name="TestPackage.BVT">
   <methods>
    <include name="testLogin"></include>
    <include name="testAddToCart"></include>
    ...
    <include name="test999 etc"></include>
   </methods>
  </class>
 </classes>
</test>
```

I've also tried preserve-order:

```
<test name="BVTQA01" preserve-order="true">
 <classes>
  <class name="TestPackage.TestBVT" />
 </classes>
</test>
```

but it's apparently ignored if I don't add a list of methods and the maintenance nightmare of 'include name' lists...

So currently I'm just listing my test classes in the xml file (as above- TestBVT which has 20 methods, etc.), and controlling test run order with 'depends on' annotations on the tests themselves.
However this is not ideal as I am creating dependencies on every method. And I want to remove the dependencies where they are not really necessary.
I only want to use 'depends on' when there is a real dependency.

I've also searched for creating the xml automatically from my @Test annotated methods. But the solutions posted are not clear on how to actually implement.

Any feedback on how to just make testNg run through my test classes from top to bottom, in order written, without any random sorting- or maintenance heavy list generation would be wonderful.
Thanks in advance,

JR

Comment: I personally don't understand why you would want this.  The nature of testing is that, for the most part, you want your tests to be distinct and independent.  Could you give us more info as to why this is desirable in your case, and we could give you an alternative way to do it?

Comment: why wud u run tcs sequentially? maintenance? Maintenance I believe is more to do with ur coding then the execution sequence..forget sequential..run parallely an

Comment: Yeah, I expected these questions. Most of the posts I've read people looking for a way to control ordering in testNg get this response. Sometimes order is important. EG the scenario where you need to create a user and assign permissions, and logout as admin, login as the new user, and verify they can see the report. Yes, this could be one test case. But really it should be more like five or ten smaller tests. Also, if one field is not properly accepting phone number in say user creation, you don't want it to stop the whole test. Ordering is critical, as are specific dependencies.

Comment: Exactly the problem that I am facing!! I had posted an issue on TestNG's github repository as a feature. No response till now :( The inflexibility of TestNG is becoming a nightmare.

Comment: @niharika_neo Why would you not run test cases sequentially? When you want to execute a certain scenario in a flow (For example, UI automation tests) then a sequence IS necessary.

Comment: @JackRyan I really get your pain!! It's not even like there are many other options available for frameworks like TestNG :(

Comment: Please check this post: [Exactly related query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18484969/running-dependent-and-independent-test-methods-in-expected-sequence)
Similar issue that we are facing. And we have no resolution till now.

Comment: Yeah, totally agreed. No ability to run tests in the most intuitive way to design and maintain (in order written) is just a glaring defect of testNG. We really shouldn't have to patch it up with all these hacks to make it do what it should do by default. Crazy how such intelligent devs could miss such an obvious requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use priority annotations, they're not standard part of TestNG, but are made by the author of the framework as well. Of course, now instead of managing 1 xml file, you'll have to keep track of priorities for all of your 130 tests, but nevertheless you'll have a finer level of control using priorities. Priority annotations are described here: http://beust.com/weblog/2008/03/29/test-method-priorities-in-testng/

Comment: Nice suggestion. Unfortunately for me it will be the same maintenance nightmare. If I have 50 tests in a class and want to add one in the middle I have to manually renumber all the tests. I will consider making more test classes and adding priorities to sets of say ten at at time. Its really not ideal but a possible workaround if no other solution to just run them automatically in the order written is provided.

Comment: Hmm, just thought of... I could number them 10, 20, 30, etc. That way I can always ad an 11, 12, 13 if needed... Maybe this will work after all.

Comment: Using priorities is the worst way of going for maintaining test method order! For UI Automation tests where the actual UI test code logic is so strongly coupled with the AUT that a lot of time goes in maintaining the core test code itself, a test developer should not need to worry about working his way through such problems of unit test frameworks he's using for UI automation.

Comment: This was the solution I went with and it's working well enough... That being said dependency annotations break priority annotations so you have to be very careful to use one or the other. Mixing them can have unexpected results. Still this is the best answer- thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to run the TestNG programatically.

```
package com.shn.test;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.testng.TestNG;
import org.testng.xml.XmlClass;
import org.testng.xml.XmlSuite;
import org.testng.xml.XmlTest;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import com.shn.demos.RunDemo;

public class RunSuite{

    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        TestNG testNG = new TestNG();
        List<XmlSuite> suites = new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();

        //pass the name of Suite, Name of the groups to be executed & name of test
        suites.add(createSuite("SuiteDemo", "groupName1", "testName"));

        testNG.setSuiteThreadPoolSize(1);
        testNG.setXmlSuites(suites);

        testNG.run();
    }

    public static XmlSuite createSuite(String suiteName, String groupName, String testName) {
        XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
        suite.setName(suiteName);
        suite.setParallel(XmlSuite.PARALLEL_NONE);

        LinkedHashMap<String, String> suiteParams = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        //Put in the parameters out here which are required @ suite level
        suiteParams.put("SuiteKey1", "SuiteValue1");
        suiteParams.put("SuiteKey2", "SuiteValue2");
        suite.setParameters(suiteParams);

        XmlTest test = new XmlTest(suite);

        test.setName(testName);
        test.addIncludedGroup(groupName);
        //Put in the parametes out here wich are required @ test level
        test.addParameter("testKey1", "testValue1");
        test.addParameter("testKey2", "testValue2");

        List<XmlClass> clazzes = new ArrayList<XmlClass>();

        //This is your class under test
        XmlClass clazz = new XmlClass(Foo.class);
        clazzes.add(clazz);
        test.setClasses(clazzes);
        List<XmlTest> tests = new ArrayList<XmlTest>();
        tests.add(test);
        suite.setTests(tests);
        return suite;
    }
}
```

I am only aware of setPreserveOrder() havent really tried it though.
Let me know if it works for you

Comment: I'm giving it a try. What includes do you use for this? I have: import org.testng.TestNG;
import org.testng.xml.XmlSuite;
import org.testng.xml.XmlTest;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

Comment: Oops hit enter... Anyway I have the above includes, and getting 'cannot resolve symbol' .setName, .setParallel, .setPreserveOrder, etc.

Comment: Edited my answer with the includes. Retry & let me know.

Comment: Can you please explain how this is supposed to work? How do I use this with standard testNG functionality? You can see above how I'm using the xml files to run testNG. I have several classes and can easily comment out which classes are run, or easily change the order in the xml. How do I chose which classes run in this solution? How do I pass parameters that are in my xml file, etc. Also, what does foo represent. It's red so I assume it needs assignment to something... More detail please.

Comment: I played with this some more. I put the code you provided above into a class with my test classes, in the same package. I replaced 'foo' with a class name 'TestBVT' in this case first posted above, then replaced TestPackage.TestBVT (in the xml) with TestPackage.testSuite. And ran the XML as normal. But my IDE (IDEA) just says all tests passed before any are actually run. It looks like either I am not using your code properly or the List in your code is not properly adding the test methods from the specified class. Any suggestions to move forward much appreciated. Its promising if it works.

Comment: Looks like you are executing the XML. But then that would not be required. You should execute the class itself. I presumed that you would have created a main method & called the class from there. To make things simpler, I have modified my answer to include a main method & then call the createSuite method from there. Just Copy Paste the above class onto your IDE, modify testName, GroupName, ClassName. Add parameters @ Suite & test levels & run the class itself but not XML

Comment: I've tried it but still a few errors- 'foo' is still not recognized. And I can't seem to find which package is 'com.shn.demos.RunDemo'? Also, my suites and groups are defined in testng xml files, and in test ng annotations respectively. Will these work?

Comment: [Suite: "GUIReskinQA03"   [Test: "test01" verbose:1[parameters:environment=>QA03][metagroups:] [included: BVT ][excluded: ]  classes:[XmlClass class=TestPackage.TestBVTGUIReskin]  packages:]  ]

Comment: Edit: comments only editable for 5 mins. Anyway... I spent some time on it and am now getting 30 tests run and 30 failed. It is a step forward as there are 30 tests in my BVT class. My class name is TestPackage.TestBVT. I send an environment parameter to a @BeforeClass. And each test in the class has a 'groups = BVT' annotation. So I'm not sure why it is failing. Here is the suite being created by createSuite:  [Suite: "GUIReskinQA03"   [Test: "test01" verbose:1[parameters:environment=>QA03][metagroups:] [included: BVT ][excluded: ]  classes:[XmlClass class=TestPackage.TestBVT]  packages:]  ]

Comment: I cannot tell the exact reason for failure until I know the exact code in your class annotated with BeforeGroups. Taking, a wild guess, maybe you are passing an incorrect parameter into the class due to which all tests are failing. Why don't you add a breakpoint in your BeforeGroups or your test class & run it in debug mode?

Comment: Yes. Thank you I am still working on this one. Will give some feedback shortly. I am also trying the priorities annotation but there are some issues. Apparently with groups. Groups mess up the order. So with priorities and depends on and groups it does get complicated to maintain workflow. If I can just figure out the logic it applies and why groups mess everything up then I can get to the best solution. Just FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18608666/selenium-and-testng-using-both-dependson-and-priority-issue

Answer (score 1):

You can automatically generate priority annotation for each test method by implementing and registering IAnnotationTransformer, which reads method line number using javassist and assigns it as a TestNG test priority.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import javassist.*

import org.testng.IAnnotationTransformer;
import org.testng.annotations.ITestAnnotation;

public class AssignTestPriorityTransformer implements IAnnotationTransformer
{
    static ClassPool s_ClassPool = ClassPool.getDefault(); 

    @Override
    public void transform(ITestAnnotation p_annotation, Class p_testClass, Constructor p_testConstructor, Method p_testMethod)
    {
        p_annotation.setPriority(getMethodLineNumber(p_testMethod));
    }
    private int getMethodLineNumber(Method p_testMethod)
    {
        try
        {
            CtClass cc = s_ClassPool.get(p_testMethod.getDeclaringClass().getCanonicalName());
            CtMethod methodX = cc.getDeclaredMethod(p_testMethod.getName());
            return methodX.getMethodInfo().getLineNumber(0);        
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Getting of line number of method "+p_testMethod+" failed", e);
        }
    }
}
```

and register that listener in your XML file

```
<suite name="Suite" parallel="false">
<listeners>
    <listener class-name="AssignTestPriorityTransformer" />
</listeners>
<test name="All tests">
    <classes>
        <class name="tests.YourTests"/>
    </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

The AssignTestPriorityTransformer will assure that methods marked by @Test annotation will be processed in same order like they are defined in the java source code of the test class.